# Can't upload raw string (csv or json) using S3 pre-signed url

Tags: python, curl, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-api-gateway

Following instructions on this link using Lambda and API Gateway: https://sookocheff.com/post/api/uploading-large-payloads-through-api-gateway/ I have a setup that allows me to get a pre-signed URL and upload files. I've tested using CURL and it has worked.

But when I try to send raw string (csv format or json format) it fails!

Example of what **works**

```
curl --request PUT --upload-file Testing.csv "**pre signed upload url**"
```

Example of what **doesn't work**

```
curl --request PUT -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "this is raw data" "**pre signed upload url**"
curl --request PUT --data "this is raw data" "**pre signed upload url**"
```

Am I making the call incorrectly? Should I be switching to POST and what would the call look like then?

Comment: Please post what is the error do you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was specifying the content-type during the pre-signed url generation and then the same one in the CURL put command. Figured out thanks to answer here: [S3 PUT doesn't work with pre-signed URL in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871669/s3-put-doesnt-work-with-pre-signed-url-in-javascript) and pointer from @Kannaiyan in the right direction regarding content-types

Answer (score 0):

It is not becoz of self signed url, it is becoz of content type with the API Gateway set to,

```
consumes:
- application/json
produces:
- application/json
```

You add additional content types, it should make it through.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I tried to send json data, see following CURL and it failed: 
`curl --request PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"OrganizationId":"5678"},{"ParticipantId":"testing1","DeviceId":"906806716","id":"6","url":"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox","title":"Gmail","dateAdded":1473059685965,"localTime":-330},{"ParticipantId":"testing1","DeviceId":"906806716","id":"7","url":"https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive","title":"Google Drive","dateAdded":1473342198128,"localTime":-330}' "**self signed upload url"`